# How to control the visibility from code behind VB.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I'm having a problem: I have a RadComboBox on Client Side if the user select a value that coming from the DB I'm showing tr and RadDateTimePicker with the current date and time.
The thing is after I'm saving the form I'm disabling all the controls on the form the problem is after I'm saving the tr is disappearing but I have all the rest of the controls.
How can I prevent that from happened?????
(the initial behavior is not to show the tr unless the user selecting a value from the RadComboBox)

ASPX code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="GeneralFontShape" style="height:15px; vertical-align:top; border: 0px solid red;">
        Status:
    </td>
    <td class="GeneralFontShape" style="height:15px; border: 0px solid red; vertical-align:top;">
        <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="rcbStatus" Width="250px" CheckBoxes="False" TabIndex="10" Enabled="True" EmptyMessage="Select Status" OnClientSelectedIndexChanged="StatusCheck"></telerik:RadComboBox>        
    </td>

<tr id="EndingTime" style="visibility:hidden;">
     <td class="GeneralFontShape" style="height:15px; vertical-align:top; border: 0px solid red;" >
       <div id="divEndingTime" runat="server" visible="true"> Ending Time:</div> 
    </td>
    <td class="GeneralFontShape"  style="height:15px; border: 0px solid red; vertical-align:top;">
    <div id="divrdtpEndingTime" runat="server" visible="true">
       <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtpEndingTime" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" Visible="true"
            DateInput-Width="170px" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" Width="250px" Culture="en-US">
            <TimeView ID="TimeView2" runat="server" CellSpacing="-1"></TimeView>
            <TimePopupButton HoverImageUrl="" ImageUrl="" />
            <Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" EnableKeyboardNavigation="true" >
                <SpecialDays>
                    <telerik:RadCalendarDay Repeatable="Today" Date="" ItemStyle-BackColor="lightblue"></telerik:RadCalendarDay>
                </SpecialDays>                                       
            </Calendar>
            <DateInput ID="DateInput3" runat="server" ToolTip="Date input" LabelWidth="60px">                                        
                <EnabledStyle Width="150px" />                                        
            </DateInput>
            <DatePopupButton HoverImageUrl="" ImageUrl="" />
        </telerik:RadDateTimePicker> 
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS Code:

```
    function StatusCheck(sender, args) {
    var status = $find("<%= rcbStatus.ClientID %>");
    var datePickerEndingTime = $find("<%= rdtpEndingTime.ClientID %>");
//  var EndingTime = datePickerEndingTime.get_selectedDate();
    var item = status.get_text();
    if (item == "Close") {
        document.getElementById('EndingTime').style.visibility = 'visible'
        datePickerEndingTime.set_visible(true);
        var nowDate = new Date();
        datePickerEndingTime.set_selectedDate(nowDate)
    } else {
        document.getElementById('EndingTime').style.visibility = 'hidden'
        datePickerEndingTime.set_visible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, your title ask about code behind (so [tag:vb.net]) but `StatusCheck` is in-page [tag:javascript]. Can you specify on your question? I think it's better for you to use the code behind in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a style sheet class to make the TR visible or invisible and in your javascript change this behavior as below:

Your style sheet class:

> ```
>  .hidden { display: none !important;   visibility: hidden !important; }
> ```

Your TR element:

> ```
> <tr id="EndingTime" class="hidden">
> ```

Your **JQuery** code: (you need jquery to use the code below)

> ```
> function StatusCheck(sender, args) {
>      .....
>      if (item == "Close") {
>            $("#EndingTime").removeClass("hidden");
>            ....
>      }else {
>            $("#EndingTime").addClass("hidden");
>            ....
>      }
> }
> ```

and you can do the same thing for the rest of your elements as well.

Comment: Thank you for you replay....The Issue is on the beginning I'm hiding the tr and based on what the user selected I'm showing the tr. after the form has been saved the tr is disappeared

Comment: Its not working its crashing on JS when its getting to that row  $find("#EndingTime").removeClass("hidden");

Comment: he is using JQuery to add and remove the class, document.getElementById('#EndingTime').attributes.setNamedItem('class', 'hidden') should help

Comment: I've just taken the "$find" out of the code, and you need jQuery to make that work though.

Comment: Don't blindly ussume people are using jQuery, it is not tagged in the question and the code supplied does not indicate jQuery is being used `$` is not just used in jQuery. `$find` may be a user created function.

Comment: [`$find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397441%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a standard microsoft function, it must work on a webform asp.net project. Also telerik controls use jquery, to enable the version used by the controls just add this script `window.$ = $telerik.$;`.

Comment: I think this solution it's not good: @user3188868 need to control the "ending time" visibility server-side for better maintainability of the ajaxification.